# 2 Activities & A Dialog

Tags: android

Consider the following use case.
Activity 1 starts Activity 2. Activity 2 is currently in foreground. Now, Activity 1 wants to display a Dialog. Is it possible for Activity 1 to display a Dialog? What will be the error display, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity 1 cannot display anything. Activity 1 is not running when Activity 2 is in the foreground. Re-read the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).